# New Line in Export-CSV not working

Tags: powershell

I want to insert a blank new line when exporting to CSV, but what I get is "1" inserted instead of blank new line. Here is the code I am using:

```
foreach($Group in $Groups) {
Get-QADGroupMember $Group | select  Name | Export-CSV C:\Users\Nikhil.Tamhankar\Desktop\temp\GroupsInfo.CSV -NoTypeInformation -Append -Encoding UTF8 -UseCulture
$newLine = "`n"
$newLine | Export-CSV C:\Users\Nikhil.Tamhankar\Desktop\temp\GroupsInfo.CSV -NoTypeInformation -Append -Encoding UTF8 -UseCulture
}
```

Please suggest how I can get a blank new line inserted after every entry made.

Comment: `Export-Csv` tries to "discover" the properties of the object, in this case a string - which only has one property, the `Length` - which happens to be 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code is just outputting a single column of group names. If that is the case then I would not even bother with CSV output at that point and just use `Set-Content`. Adding in the newline then would be fairly easy.

```
$Groups | ForEach-Object{
    (Get-QADGroupMember $_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name) + "`n" 
} | Set-Content C:\Users\Nikhil.Tamhankar\Desktop\temp\GroupsInfo.CSV -Encoding UTF8
```

I used a more pipeline friendly `foreach-object` loop so you don't have to keep using append.

Answer (score 1):

`Export-Csv` tries to "discover" the properties of the object, in this case a string - which only has one property, the `Length` - which happens to be 1.

Use `Add-Content` or `Out-File -Append -NoNewline` (version 5 only) to append to an existing file:

```
"" |Add-Content -Path C:\Users\Nikhil.Tamhankar\Desktop\temp\GroupsInfo.CSV
```